# AuthenticationPrincipal returns empty UserDetails object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I'm trying to secure my api endpoints by spring security + jwt token. So far, the token generator and veficator work well. The problem arises when i use `AuthenthicationPrincipal` in method argument to get current `UserDetails`. I have my class `Account` implement `UserDetails`, and my `TokenAuthenticationProvider` provide the necessary `Account` based on header bearer's token.

Partial code of configuration and controller :

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${spring.data.rest.basePath}")
    private String apiBasePath;
    private RequestMatcher protectedUrls;
    private RequestMatcher publicUrls;

    @NotNull
    private final TokenAuthenticationProvider provider;

    @PostConstruct
    private void postConstruct() {
        protectedUrls = new OrRequestMatcher(
                // Api
                new AntPathRequestMatcher(apiBasePath + "/**")
        );
        publicUrls = new NegatedRequestMatcher(protectedUrls);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                // when request a protected page without having authenticated
                .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(forbiddenEntryPoint(),
                        protectedUrls)
                .and()
                // Authenticating with rest requests
                .authenticationProvider(provider)
                .addFilterBefore(restAuthenticationFilter(), // injecting TokenAuthenticationProvider here
                        AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(protectedUrls)
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                // Disable server rendering for logging
                .formLogin().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .logout().disable();
    }
}
```

Tracing in debug mode shows that the `TokenAuthenticationProvider` has retrieved correctly the `Account`. Only when called in the controller, an empty `Account` is returned (`null` attributes)

```java
@RepositoryRestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@BasePathAwareController
@RequestMapping(path = "account")
class AccountController {
    @GetMapping("current")
    @ResponseBody
    Account getCurrent(@AuthenticationPrincipal Account account) {
        return account;
    }
}
```

The filter chain is correct though :

```
servletPath:/api/account/current
pathInfo:null
headers: 
authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInppcCI6IkdaSVAi...
user-agent: PostmanRuntime/7.19.0
accept: */*
cache-control: no-cache
postman-token: 73da9eb7-2ee1-43e8-9cd0-2658e4f32d1f
host: localhost:8090
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
connection: keep-alive


Security filter chain: [
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  CsrfFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  TokenAuthenticationFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]
```

I looked into some tutorials and questions but could not deduce any suitable answer.

https://octoperf.com/blog/2018/03/08/securing-rest-api-spring-security/ (which inspires my current implementation)

https://svlada.com/jwt-token-authentication-with-spring-boot/#jwt-authentication

[@AuthenticationPrincipal return empty User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41049750/authenticationprincipal-return-empty-user) (this one use `DelegatingFlashMessagesConfiguration` which does not exist in my case)

Does it have anything to do with the order of configuration or filters ?

Comment: I have the same problem, any solution?

Comment: In debug mode, i see clearly the Authenthication is contained in SecurityContextHolder. However, the AuthenticationPrincipal annotation didn't pick it up for some reason. My workaround thus is to call directly by `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()`

Comment: I found that this has something to do with the BasePathAwareController annotation. In my case a controller annotated with it would not receive a populated principal object, whereas the exact same controller annotated with RestController got the info just fine.

Comment: @JensWegar I've never noticed it. Did you find any fix?

Comment: @phet nope, not yet. For the time being I worked around it by creating a bean which in turn calls the SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal(). Didn't want to call a static method directly all over the place because it makes unit testing harder. This way I can easily mock and inject the principal when needed

Comment: The idea of bean is really nice. I would give a try.

Answer (score 1):

For @AuthenticationPrincipal to work I need to override addArgumentResolvers

```
@Configuration
public class WevMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    protected void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        argumentResolvers.add(new AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver());
    }    
}
```

`new AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver()`use import `org.springframework.security.web.method.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver`

Custom class implement UserDetails

```
public class UserPrincipal implements UserDetails {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    
    private ObjectId id;        
    private String name;    
    private String username;    
    private String email;    
    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;    
    //constructor, getter, etc    
}
```

Now working really well.

```
@GetMapping(value="/me")    
    public User getMe(@AuthenticationPrincipal UserPrincipal currentUser){
        logger.debug("name: "+currentUser.getUsername());       
        return this.userService.findByUsername(currentUser.getUsername());
    }
```

Comment: +1 
Documentation for pre spring-security 4 states you must provide your own  `AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver`. I took this to assume declaring tat bean alone in context is enough. It wasnt. Your answer should be in documentation